# Can't find all <script> Elements in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have the following code:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.setAttribute("width", width);
iframe.setAttribute("height", height);
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

var  idocument = iframe.contentWindow.document;
iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
iframe.contentWindow.document.write(str);
iframe.contentWindow.document.close();

scriptElems = idocument.getElementsByTagName("script");
console.log(scriptElems); //line 1
for (var i = 0; i < scriptElems.length; i++)
    console.log(scriptElems[i]); //line 2
```

Here, str is a global string that has a whole HTML document in it.

This HTML  has various resources(images, scripts, css, etc) and all of them will give 404 because they don't actually exist.

But I do have the css, scripts, etc as strings available to me. But their actual paths specified in the HTML don't exist.

What I want to achieve is to replace the src/href of every script, css, etc with their data inline (using data uris).

The problem is that line 1 in the above code prints an array of 6 script elements, but the loop just below it prints just one and hence I can not replace the JS in the script tags. What could be the reason?

Is this some catch about script tags?
Also if I try to get the script tags using this: `console.log($(idocument).find("script"));`

I just get one script element.

Please Help!

**UPDATE**

Thare are also some script tags with inline javascript code that depend on the other scripts that have been included in the page before them. So, this is causing error in those inline script. So, could this be the reason? Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: `document.open('text/htmlreplace')` – what is that? Never seen that before – quick Google search suggests that `document.open('text/html','replace')` might be what you meant here?

Comment: @CBroe: Yeah right, Edited that in the question - turns out I don't need replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was such a silly mistake. I should try to access the script elements once the iframe has loaded, so the correct way would be:

```
iframe.onload = function() {
    scriptElems = idocument.getElementsByTagName("script");
    console.log(scriptElems); //line 1
    for (var i = 0; i < scriptElems.length; i++)
        console.log(scriptElems[i]); //line 2
}
```